# UICollectionView custom layout. Supplementary views are not shown or queried

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to create a simple custom layout for `UICollectionView` to use programmatically (i.e. without Interface Builder).

I do everything according to the docs:

1. Subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and prepare my layout
2. override `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)` and return corresponding layout attributes
3. add `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)` implementation where I return my supplementary view

My problem is that neither

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)
```

nor

```
layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)
```

is getting called, so I can't see my supplementary views.

I have double-checked my implementations both for layout and for supplementary views creation but I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it is not enough to have

```
layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

which return attributes for supplementary views. One also needs to return attributes for supplementary views in

```
layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

My mistake was that I was **only returning layout attributes for cells** in

```
layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

Once I added layout attributes for supplementary views into values returned by

```
layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

I got my datasource methods called and supplementary views returned.

**EDIT**: This answer covers iOS10 SDK. I haven't tried on earlier versions

Comment: layoutAttributesForItem() ? not for RECT?

Comment: I believe he meant `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?`. At least that's what was lacking the attributes for the supplementary view in my case.

Comment: This answer is wrong. From the documentation for layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath): "You use this method to provide layout information only for items that have a corresponding cell. Do not use it for supplementary views or decoration views." The correct function is layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect): "Your implementation should return attributes for all visual elements, including cells, supplementary views, and decoration views."

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good but some sample code would be helpful:

```
override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

    let layoutAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: elementKind, with: indexPath)

    if elementKind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
        layoutAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: contentWidth, height: headerHeight)
        layoutAttributes.zIndex = Int.max - 3
    }

    return layoutAttributes
}
```